# The Ubuntu installation does not create swap partition

Tags: partitioning, swap

The Ubuntu installation does not create swap partition. This issue happen with both 12.04.2 and 13.04.

I tested it with two diferents pc and with a virtual machine in virtual box into Ubuntu. I tried both automatic and manual installation options during installation.

The partition is created but with errors and the system can not mount the partition swap at startup.

I solved the problem by booting the system from pendrive, then start gparted and format the partition again. This worked for only a few days.

Comment: Did you do anything in particular while installing? Like Full Disk Encryption or set up Logical Volume Manager (LVM)?

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, while i installed the system i choosed the option to encripted the home partition. But i always do this since 10.04, and  never had this problem.

Comment: the content of /etc/fstab is:file system> 
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=59a5ed6f-0962-4146-b993-11e0251226b8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
UUID=3d3b2e50-5705-46de-a7cb-7bdc590243cf /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
#UUID=ad6834c0-9b81-45fe-a067-9595eb567c7c none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0